# What I'm doing wrong filling this vector of pair?

Tags: c++, vector

If I do:

```
vector<string> vec_jets;

double values[] = {
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet1"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet2"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet3"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet4"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet5"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet6"),
    transEnergy(map_jets, "jet7") };

for( int j = 1; j <= Njets; j++){
  oss << "jet" << j;
  vec_jets.push_back( oss.str() );
  oss.str("");
}

vector<pair<string,double> > jets_pt( vec_jets.size() );

// for( int k = 0; k < Njets; k++ ){ 
  // if( jet_preselection(map_jets,map_leps,vec_jets[k],jets_emfr[k]) )

        transform(
            vec_jets.begin(),
            vec_jets.end(), 
            values,
            jets_pt.begin(),
            make_pair<string,double>
        );

//    }
```

I have the output I want, which is, for example

```
jet1 32.4717
```

But, if I uncomment the `for` loop and the `if` condition, it seems that the vector is not filled anymore, if I ask to cout it, I get only `0` always.

The function in the `if` statement is just a bool

```
bool jet_preselection(
    map<string, TLorentzVector> map_jets,
    map<string, TLorentzVector> map_leps,
    string vec_jets,
    double jet_emfr )
{

        return ( map_jets[vec_jets].E()*sin(map_jets[vec_jets].Theta()) > 15 
            && jet_emfr < 0.9
            && fabs(map_jets[vec_jets].PseudoRapidity()) > 2.5
            && ( map_jets[vec_jets].DeltaR(map_leps["lep1"]) > 0.4
                && map_jets[vec_jets].DeltaR(map_leps["lep2"]) > 0.4
                && map_jets[vec_jets].DeltaR(map_leps["lep3"]) > 0.4 );
}
```

Comment: Your `jet_preselection` has a for loop but returns on the first iteration.

Comment: You realise that `jet_preselection()` only looks at the first jet in the vector, and causes undefined behaviour if the vector is empty? I'm guessing the body of the `for` loop should be more like `if (stuff) return true;`, with a `return false;` after the loop.

Comment: You're right! I'm an idiot, modified the thing and didn't see that. I try to fix.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've removed the for loop in `jet_preselection()` which was unnececary, and still have the same behaviour.

Comment: @drkg4b Does `jet_preselection()` ever return true?  Generally speaking, you've got too much code in your example and it references a lot of things that aren't shown.  **However** rather than adding to the example things like definitions of DeltaR or PseudoRapidity, consider if they are central to demonstrating the issue or not...and if not, remove them.  Isolate the problem and produce a short sample others can compile to reproduce it: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @HostileFork I found that `jet_preselection()` returns true after a lot of iteration, so nothing wrong with it. Thanks for the help anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of complex interdependancies in your code that make it difficult to diagnose the problem.  But I can tell you that in:

```
bool jet_preselection(map<string, TLorentzVector> map_jets, map<string, TLorentzVector> map_leps, string vec_jets, double jet_emfr)
```

...you are passing `map_jets` and `map_leps` *by value* rahter than by-reference (preferred) or by-pointer, so that when you call this function a complete copy of those `map`s is constructed.

You may consider changing how you pass these parameters.  Perhaps passing copies of these maps would change the states of them in such a way so that `jet_preselection` would fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried what you suggested but still not get what I want!